# Help passing XML String to RecordSet

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, vbscript, ado

What I would like to do is dump an XML String into RecordSet. The problem I am having is that the code seems to work fine if I saved the XML String first to a file and then read from the file which I think is redundant. However, when I want to read from string, I get the error

**RecordSet cannot be created. Source XML is incomplete or invalid. 80004005**

My XML String is in the form

```
<portfolio>
   <stock>
      <shares>100</shares>
      <symbol>MSFT</symbol>
      <price>$70.00</price>
      <info>
         <companyname>Microsoft Corporation</companyname>
         <website>http://www.microsoft.com</website>
      </info>
   </stock>
   <stock>
      <shares>100</shares>
      <symbol>AAPL</symbol>
      <price>$107.00</price>
      <info>
         <companyname>Apple Computer, Inc.</companyname>
         <website>http://www.apple.com</website>
      </info>
   </stock>
   <stock>
      <shares>100</shares>
      <symbol>DELL</symbol>
      <price>$50.00</price>
      <info>
         <companyname>Dell Corporation</companyname>
         <website>http://www.dell.com</website>
      </info>
    </stock>
    <stock>
       <shares>100</shares>
       <symbol>INTC</symbol>
       <price>$115.00</price>
       <info>
          <companyname>Intel Corporation</companyname>
          <website>http://www.intel.com</website>
       </info>
   </stock>
</portfolio>
```

And the code I am using to convert the XML String(That I am having the problem with) is

```
Public Function RecordsetFromXMLString(sXML As String) As Recordset

    Dim oStream As ADODB.Stream
    Set oStream = New ADODB.Stream

    oStream.Open
    oStream.WriteText sXML   'Give the XML string to the ADO Stream

    oStream.Position = 0    'Set the stream position to the start

    Dim oRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
    Set oRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

    oRecordset.Open oStream    'Open a recordset from the stream

    oStream.Close
    Set oStream = Nothing

    Set RecordsetFromXMLString = oRecordset  'Return the recordset

    Set oRecordset = Nothing

End Function
```

Please, your help will be greatly appreciated.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810621

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/263247

I already tried using this below

```
Public Function RecordsetFromXMLDocument(XMLDOMDocument) 
    Dim oRecordset 
    Set oRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset.6.0")
    oRecordset.Open XMLDOMDocument 'pass the DOM Document instance as the Source argument

    Set RecordsetFromXMLDocument = oRecordset  'return the recordset

    Set oRecordset = Nothing
End Function
```

But still ran into the same issue.

---

Code I used to Format my DomDocumentData into the ADO XML Persistent Format I required for this

```
'*******************************************************************************************
' SCHEMA GENERATOR
'*******************************************************************************************
'parentnodepath -- XPath to the Main Node/Table/RowCollection
'parentnodepath -- Name of the Main Node/Table/RowCollection
Function CreateSchemafromNode(XMLDocument,parentnodepath, parentnodeName)
        Dim schema, stemp, MyArray,nodename, childnodelist,counter, n, x, tempnode
        schema = TextWriterSchemaNameSpaceHeader()
        schema=schema & TextWriterSchemaHeader(parentnodeName)
        'LOOP HERE 
          counter = 0

            For Each stemp In XMLDocument.SelectSingleNode(parentnodePath).ChildNodes(0).ChildNodes
                    counter = counter + 1
                    schema = schema & TextWriterSchemaRowAttributeElement(stemp.NodeName, counter, "")
            Next
        'END LOOOP HERE
            schema=schema & TextWriterSchemaSchemaEnd
            schema =schema &  TextWriterSchemaRowHeader
           'BEGIN FIRST LOOP HERE -- FOR EACH TOP NODE --ROW
                For Each n In XMLDocument.SelectSingleNode(parentnodePath).ChildNodes
                        schema =schema & TextWriterSchemaAddRowBegin()
                    'BEGIN SECOND LOOP HERE -- FOR EACH CHILD OF TOP NODE -- NODE VALUE IN CURRENT ROW -- FOR EACH CHILDNODELIST NAME
                    For Each x In n.ChildNodes
                            schema = schema & TextWriterSchemaAddRowFieldNameValue(x.NodeName, x.text) 
                    'END SECOND LOOP HERE 
                    Next
                    schema =schema & TextWriterSchemaAddRowEnd()
           Next 
        'END FIRST LOOP HERE 
        schema =schema & TextWriterSchemaRowEnd()
        schema =schema &TextWriterSchemaNameSpaceEnd()

        CreateSchemafromNode=schema
End Function 


Function TextWriterSchemaNameSpaceHeader()
  Dim schemaString 

    schemaString= "<xml xmlns:s='"
    schemaString= schemaString & "uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882' " & vbCrLf & vbTab
    schemaString= schemaString & ("xmlns:dt='")
    schemaString= schemaString & "uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882' " & vbCrLf & vbTab
  ' schemaString= schemaString & ("xmlns:dt='")
  ' schemaString= schemaString & "uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882' " & vbCrLf & vbTab
    schemaString= schemaString & "xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset' "  & vbCrLf & vbTab
    schemaString=schemaString & " xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'> " & vbCrLf 
    TextWriterSchemaNameSpaceHeader = schemaString 
End Function


Function TextWriterSchemaHeader(recordname)
     Dim schemaString 
            schemaString= "<s:Schema id='RowsetSchema'>"& vbCrLf & vbTab
            schemaString= schemaString &"<s:ElementType name='" & recordname & "' content='eltOnly'>" & vbCrLf 
            TextWriterSchemaHeader = schemaString 
End Function

Function TextWriterSchemaRowAttributeElement(rowname, rowordernumber, rowtype)
    Dim schemaString 
        schemaString=vbTab & vbTab & "<s:AttributeType  name='" & rowname & "'  rs:number='" & rowordernumber & "'  />" & vbCrLf 
        TextWriterSchemaRowAttributeElement = schemaString
End Function

Function TextWriterSchemaSchemaEnd()
      Dim schemaString 
        schemaString=vbTab & vbTab & "<s:extends type='rs:rowbase'/>" & vbCrLf 
        schemaString= schemaString &vbTab &  "</s:ElementType>" & vbCrLf 
        schemaString= schemaString & "</s:Schema>"  & vbCrLf 
        TextWriterSchemaSchemaEnd =schemaString
End Function

Function TextWriterSchemaRowHeader()
        Dim schemaString 
            schemaString= vbTab & "<rs:data>" & vbCrLf 
            TextWriterSchemaRowHeader = schemaString
End function

Function TextWriterSchemaAddRowBegin()
      Dim schemaString 
        schemaString=vbTab & "<z:row "
        TextWriterSchemaAddRowBegin=schemaString
End function

Function TextWriterSchemaAddRowFieldNameValue(FieldName, FieldValue)
    Dim schemaString 
            schemaString= FieldName & "='" & FieldValue & "' "
            TextWriterSchemaAddRowFieldNameValue=schemaString
End function

Function TextWriterSchemaAddRowEnd()
        Dim schemaString
           schemaString="/>"  & vbCrLf 
           TextWriterSchemaAddRowEnd=schemaString
End function


Function TextWriterSchemaRowEnd()
         Dim schemaString
              schemaString=vbTab & "</rs:data>" & vbCrLf 
               TextWriterSchemaRowEnd=schemaString
End function

Function TextWriterSchemaNameSpaceEnd()
         Dim schemaString
               schemaString="</xml>"  & vbCrLf 
               TextWriterSchemaNameSpaceEnd=schemaString
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error, because the XML you are supplying is not in the format that ADODB.Recordset understands. The format needs to resemble the following, which is based on [XML-Data Reduced Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256208.aspx). See the documentation on the [ADO XML Persistence Format Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313112%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more information.

```
<xml xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882' 
    xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset' 
    xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'>
<s:Schema id='RowsetSchema'>
    <s:ElementType name='row' content='eltOnly'>
        <s:AttributeType name='shares' rs:number='1' />
        <s:AttributeType name='symbol' rs:number='2' />
        <s:AttributeType name='price' rs:number='3' />
        <s:extends type='rs:rowbase'/>
    </s:ElementType>
</s:Schema>
<rs:data>
    <z:row shares='100' symbol='MSFT' price='$70.00'  />
    <z:row shares='100' symbol='AAPL' price='$107.00'  />
    <z:row shares='100' symbol='DELL' price='$50.00'  />
</rs:data>
</xml>
```

In the past when working with ADO and XML I've used [XSLT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256069.aspx) to transform my XML format into ADO XML format. You can also do it programmatically. Here are a few examples (They are not VB6, but should give you an idea of what's needed).

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316337

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301468.aspx

http://etutorials.org/Programming/Web+Solutions+based+on+ASP.NET+and+ADO.NET/Part+III+Interoperability/Interoperable+Web+Applications/From+DataSet+Objects+to+ADO+Recordset+Objects/

Comment: If I were to build my XML in the way you have there by appending strings, would that work fine or is there a feature in MSXML2 or higher that could aid in converting my XML String to the right format?

Comment: You can also just use the MSXML API to build a DOMDocument, and use that at the parameter to the `Open` method of the `Recordset`, because it can use any object that implements the `IStream` interface, which IXMLDOMDocument does. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/263247

Comment: I did try this approach from that very link, passing in           objXMLDoc2 = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0")                  and ran into the very same problem.